# Explain output difference between this inner and natural join

Tags: oracle, join

> A NATURAL JOIN is a JOIN operation that creates an implicit join
>   clause for you based on the common columns in the two tables being
>   joined. A NATURAL JOIN can be an INNER join, a LEFT OUTER join, or a
>   RIGHT OUTER join. The default is INNER join. [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljnaturaljoin.html)

So a natural join can be a shorthand way of implementing inner join if both tables have a common column.

Consider following table:

```
SELECT * FROM t1;
/*
        ID PLANET  
---------- --------
         1 jupiter 
         2 earth 
*/
```

We join the table to itself:

```
SELECT first.id, first.planet FROM t1 first INNER JOIN t1 second ON first.id=second.id;
/*
        ID PLANET  
---------- --------
         1 jupiter 
         2 earth   
*/
```

Try to do the same with natural join notation:

```
SELECT id, planet FROM t1 NATURAL JOIN t1;
/*
        ID PLANET  
---------- --------
         1 jupiter 
         1 jupiter 
         2 earth   
         2 earth   
*/
```

Given that natural join here is implemented using inner join why the multiple rows?

**Update:**

Running same join with table aliases has different output:

```
SELECT id, planet FROM t1 first NATURAL JOIN t1 second;
/*
        ID PLANET  
---------- --------
         1 jupiter 
         2 earth   
*/
```

Comment: This table also has `PLANET` as a common column, is that causing the duplicates?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do: `SELECT first.id, first.planet FROM t1 first NATURAL JOIN t1 second`?

Comment: @Lennart Yes it does. I wonder why. Updated the question with output.

Comment: @Kshitiz Sharma, beats me. Looks like a bug

Comment: To me, _natural join_ is the worst idea ever. As you can see by this example... who knows what columns it's joined on (hint: you could look at the query plan). If you rename a column you risk messing up any natural joins. If you are going to write production code, please stop using natural joins now.

Comment: I would forget that Natural Join even exists at all (unless your studying for one of the Oracle SQL Certifications, LOL).  From Tom Kyte: "the natural join syntax is stupid and error prone. It does, it can, it has caused many a mistake. there is a zero percent chance I would ever use it.": https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8764523461767

Comment: According to this MOS Document-**Wrong Result with ANSI Using Join of Tables with Identical Aliases (Doc ID 2229061.1)**, there is one related bug which they are still working on. Workaround is to use different table aliases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle database does not understand ANSI join syntax internally (except `FULL OUTER JOIN`), it rewrites such queries to its own, old join syntax. If you enable optimizer trace, for example:

```
alter session set events '10053 trace name context forever, level 1';
```

And run the queries, in the generated trace file, you can view the final form of the query that is executed.

```
select id, planet from t1 ta natural join t1 tb
```

is transformed into (BP is my schema):

```
Final query after transformations:******* UNPARSED QUERY IS *******
SELECT "TB"."ID" "ID","TB"."PLANET" "PLANET" FROM "BP"."T1" "TA","BP"."T1" "TB"
WHERE "TA"."PLANET"="TB"."PLANET" AND "TA"."ID"="TB"."ID"
```

And

```
select id, planet from t1 natural join t1
```

is transformed into:

```
Final query after transformations:******* UNPARSED QUERY IS *******
SELECT "T1"."ID" "ID","T1"."PLANET" "PLANET" FROM "BP"."T1" "T1","BP"."T1" "T1"
WHERE "T1"."PLANET"="T1"."PLANET" AND "T1"."ID"="T1"."ID"
```

And this is the problem, `"T1"."PLANET"="T1"."PLANET" AND "T1"."ID"="T1"."ID"`.

But don't ask me why, it is just one of those "unexplainable" things in Oracle.

I have seen a case, where the transformation resulted in a similarly ambigiuous final query, and there was an actual error message in the trace file, still, the database returned wrong results and no error to the client.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug.

First, a self `x NATURAL JOIN x` should return the same number of rows and columns as the original table. So, the last query that returns 2 rows is correct. The 2nd query, that returns 4 rows, seems to be doing a `CROSS JOIN` instead (if you try with a table of 3 rows, it returns 9).

Second, the query should have given a `"ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined"` error or something similar because it is not allowed to have 2 tables with same alias in the same `FROM` clause.

See the tests at [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a520a84ddb6e0df1941d378275511b7d), where cross joins return this error message:

```
> SELECT id, planet FROM t1, t1;
> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

> SELECT id, planet FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t1;
> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

and the same queries [tested in Postgres](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8340536c6b08f96d207cb66303b3ad9f):

```
> SELECT * FROM t1 NATURAL JOIN t1;
> ERROR:  table name "t1" specified more than once
```